# Php MySQL Looping through the loop? I am "overlooped"

Tags: php, mysql, nested-loops

```
table: car_cat
+-----+---------+
| id  | name    |
+-----+---------+
| 1   |sedan    |
| 2   |suv      |
| 3   |truck    |
+-----+---------+


table: Cars
+-----+---------+------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
| id  | date    |         category       |      make    |  model  |    price    |
+-----+---------+------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
| 1   |01-01-18 |        sedan           |    ford      | taurus  |    15000    |
| 2   |01-01-18 |        sedan           |    ford      | fiesta  |    15000    |
| 3   |01-01-18 |        sedan           |    ford      | fucus   |    15000    |
| 4   |01-02-18 |        sedan           |    honda     | accord  |    25000    |
| 5   |01-02-18 |        sedan           |    bmw       | 535xi   |    35000    |
| 6   |01-03-18 |        suv             |    mercedes  | ml350   |    15000    |
| 7   |01-03-18 |        suv             |    mercedes  | gl350   |    35000    |
| 8   |01-03-18 |        suv             |    mercedes  | gle350  |    45000    |
| 9   |01-01-18 |        suv             |    chevrolet | suburban|    65000    |
| 10  |01-03-18 |        suv             |    chevrolet | tahoe   |    55000    |
| 11  |01-01-18 |          truck         |    ford      | f-150   |    45000    |
| 12  |01-01-18 |          truck         |    ford      | f-250   |    65000    |
| 13  |01-01-18 |          truck         |    ford      | f-350   |    85000    |
| 14  |01-01-18 |          truck         |    chevrolet |silverado|    85000    |
+-----+---------+------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
```

Output should be:

Category:

*SEDANS (loop and counts all cars from only one make and counts them)

```
FORD
+-----+---------+------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
| id  | date    |     category           |    make      |  model  |    price    |
+-----+---------+------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
| 1   |01-01-18 |        sedan           |    ford      | taurus  |   15000 |
| 2   |01-01-18 |        sedan           |    ford      | fiesta  |   15000 |
| 3   |01-01-18 |        sedan           |    ford      | fucus   |   15000 |
+-----+---------+------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
total: 3 cars, total value $45,000

HONDA
+-----+---------+------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
| id  | date    |   category     |    make  |  model  | price   |
+-----+---------+------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
| 4   |01-02-18 |        sedans          |    honda     | accord  |   25000 |
+-----+---------+------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
total: 1 car, total value $25,000

HONDA
+-----+---------+------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
| id  | date    |   category     |    make  |  model  | price   |
+-----+---------+------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
| 5   |01-02-18 |        sedans          |    bmw       | 535xi   |   35000 |
+-----+---------+------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
total: 1 car, total value $35,000
```

*SUV

```
MERCEDES
+-----+---------+------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
| id  | date    |   category     |    make  |  model  | price   |
+-----+---------+------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
| 6   |01-03-18 |        suv             |    mercedes  | ml350   |   15000 |
| 7   |01-03-18 |        suv             |    mercedes  | gl350   |   35000 |
| 8   |01-03-18 |        suv             |    mercedes  | gle350  |   45000 |
+-----+---------+------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
total: 3 cars, total value $95,000

CHEVROLET
+-----+---------+------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
| id  | date    |   category     |    make  |  model  | price   |
+-----+---------+------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
| 9   |01-01-18 |        suv             |    chevrolet | suburban|   65000 |
| 10  |01-03-18 |        suv             |    chevrolet | tahoe   |   55000 |
+-----+---------+------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
total: 2 cars, total value $120,000
```

*TRUCK

```
FORD
+-----+---------+------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
| id  | date    |   category     |    make  |  model  | price   |
+-----+---------+------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
etc ....
```

Basically code should: 
1: read through all of the record
2: group them into categories
3: List them with specific group while count them as well.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `car_cat` ORDER BY `name`";
$result = $mydb->runQuery($sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
    <table width="100%">
     <tr>
      <td colspan="6"><?php echo strtoupper($row['name']);?></td>
         </tr>  
    <tr>
     <th>id</th>
     <th>date</th>
     <th>category</th>
     <th>make</th>
     <th>model</th>
     <th>amount</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $catName = $row['name'];
    $sql_show = "SELECT * FROM `expenses` where `cat` = '$catName' ORDER BY `id` DESC";
    $result_show = $mydb->runQuery($sql_show);
    $showTotal = 0;         
    while($row_show = mysqli_fetch_array($result_show)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row_show['id'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_show['date'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_show['category'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_show['make'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_show['model'];?></td>
      <td>$<?php echo number_format((float)$row_show['price'], 2, '.', ',');?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $showTotal = $showTotal + $row_show['amount'];
    } //while
    ?>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="4" align="right">TOTAL:</td>
     <td colspan="2" align="left">$<?php echo number_format((float)$showTotal, 2, '.', ','); ?></td>
    </tr>
       </table>     
<?php   
} //while
?>
```

but this code groups it by category only. it will not group makes together and do separate tables for them. And this is what I do really need.

Thanks

Comment: whrere is your query?

Comment: will do as requested

Comment: there is no name column, and edit the question with this basic information dont post it as a comment please

Comment: no name column, just id, date, category, make, model & price

Comment: then why do you have a `ORDER BY name` ??

Comment: It groups all cars in specific category but do not group and separate by make like ( FORD, CHEVY). I need that script to separate all FORDS from SEDAN category, count them and display total value. Right now it gives me a total for all cards in SEDAN category. All FORDS plus HONDA plus BMW. i need that to be separated.

Comment: ORDER BY name groups only all cars from categories like SEDAN, SUV or TRUCK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am submitting a new answer for your question. I was able to get a solution for your question. I'd like to see a better way of doing this with recursion or without having 3 nested foreach loops. This could run very slow because it's O(n^3) but I wasn't really sure of another way.

I am including some screenshots and a JSFiddle to make sure this is the structure you are asking for: https://jsfiddle.net/Pimentelk/2duczuwd/

[image]

[image]

```
<?php

// Connect to the database:
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database', 'port');

// Retrieve all records:
$sql = 'SELECT id, date, category, make, model, price FROM cars ORDER BY category, make, model';
$results = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);

// Init your array
$cars = array();

// Build a silly array
while (list($id, $date, $category, $make, $model, $price) = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    $cars["$category"]["$make"][] = [
        'id'        => $id,
        'date'      => $date,
        'category'  => $category,
        'make'      => $make,
        'model'     => $model,
        'price'     => $price
    ];
}

// init some counter variables.
$count = 0;
$worth = 0;
?>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
<?php foreach ($cars as $category => $makes) : ?>
    <h1 align="center"><?= $category ?></h1>

    <?php foreach ($makes as $make => $values) : ?>
        <h5><?= $make ?></h5>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>date</th>
                    <th>category</th>
                    <th>make</th>
                    <th>model</th>
                    <th>price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($values as $key => $value) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?= $value['id'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $value['date'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $value['category'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $value['make'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $value['model'] ?></td>
                        <td>&#36;<?= number_format($value['price']) ?></td>

                    </tr>
                    <?php $worth += $value['price'] ?>
                    <?php $count++; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <p>total: <?= $count ?>, value: &#36;<?= number_format($worth) ?></p>
        <?php $count = 0 ?>
        <?php $worth = 0 ?>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I am looking for a query that will list group & count specific categories grouped by type of the car

Comment: this will not group it by category, make and give the count as total.

Comment: Wow - almost what I asked. Can you change it to count inside each make? To see how many sedans like `audi` is available. this would count each make separately.

Comment: Now it is all done! Works pretty fast with 1500 records. Will mark your solution. Thanks